# Test if string exists in LinkedList

Tags: c, linked-list

I have very little experience with LinkedLists and cannot figure out the logic for testing if a string is in one of the nodes. The program overall is waiting for clients to send DNS queries and then sending back a response in an infinite loop. What I would like to do is:

Determine if the LinkedList has the client requested hostname. If it is not there, add it to the LinkedList and after performing the lookup save the answer to the same node. If it is there, just give the client the answer I already looked up and stored in `answer[]`.

Here is a simplified section of code:

```
struct queryCache {
    char* hostName;
    uint8_t answer[UDP_RECV_SIZE];
    struct queryCache* next;
};
struct queryCache* qcRoot;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    // ...unrelated code

    qcRoot = malloc(sizeof(struct queryCache));
    qcRoot->hostName = 0;
    qcRoot->next = 0;

    while (1) {
        // Wait for client with recvfrom()

        char* cqHostName;
        // Code that malloc()s and strcpy()s the client hostname into cqHostName

        // Determine if cqHostName is in the cache
        int hostNameInCache = 0;
        struct queryCache* currQC = qcRoot;
        while (currQC) {
            if (!strcmp(currQC->hostName, cqHostName)) {
                puts("In the cache");
                hostNameInCache = 1;
                break;
            }
            currQC = currQC->next;
        }

        // If cqHostName is not in the cache add its name
        if (!hostNameInCache) {
            currQC->hostName = malloc(strlen(cqHostName)+1);
            strcpy(currQC->hostName, cqHostName);
            printf("Added HOSTNAME: %s to the cache\n", cqHostName);

            currQC->next = malloc(sizeof(struct queryCache));
            currQC = currQC->next;
            currQC->hostName = 0;
            currQC->next = 0;
        }

        // Code that does a recursive DNS

        // Code that will copy the response into the appropriate answer[] of the LinkedList
    }
}
```

The program seems to just exit on after the first client request without giving an error. If I remove the LinkedList code it works just fine so I'm pretty sure what is going wrong has to do with how I am checking if a string is in the LinkedList.

Comment: You might want to step through the code line by line in a debugger. It will probably help you locate the problem.

Comment: By the way, you have a possible case of *undefined behavior* in your code. After the lookup loop, the variable `currQC` will be `NULL`, and yet you dereference it when creating a new entry.

Comment: Oh, and you call `strcmp` with a `NULL` pointer as well, another case that will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: The solution is to test `currCQ->next` in the while loop then?

Comment: Yes that's a start, but that's not all of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `hostNameInCache` is 0, most likely `currQC` is `NULL`, so you can't defer it.

Change condition of your while loop as

```
#------------v
while (currQC->next) {
    if (!strcmp(currQC->hostName, cqHostName)) {
            puts("In the cache");
            hostNameInCache = 1;
            break;
        }
        currQC = currQC->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, currQC is null when you attempt to do the `currQC->hostName = malloc(strlen(cqHostName)+1);`.

The answer you accepted happens to work in order to address this specific situation, indeed, *but* in the while loop, if you do `while(currQC->next)` then *you miss checking the last item in the list*.

So, that code, introduces another problem, not apparent immediately. I would suggest checking if the next element is null, instead and break if it is like in `if (!currQC->next) break; else currQC=currQC->next`.

EDIT: Of course, my suggestion means that you will want to replace the while loop with a do {}while(1); instead, since the while condition will no longer be tested ever.

Comment: Thank you, that would have been a headache later

Comment: I just added a conditional statement after the while loop to check the last one. **Edit:** Seemed to be a simple solution to maintain the working string check

Comment: @asimes adding a condition *after* the loop does not solve the problem if you do not have the currQC to the last element in the list, so that you can add the new element. EDIT: Ah, you mean you kept the while(currQC->next) condition...Sure, that could do it, as well.

Comment: `if (currQC->next && !strcmp(currQC->next->hostName, cqHostName))`

Comment: @asimes This can cause you to miss an equality on the last item of the list, since the comparison will not be checked if currQC->next is 0.

Comment: I don't think I follow to be honest. If the next element is `0` then that means the LinkedList ended right?

Comment: @asimes Ops, sorry. You check the next element for the name. My bad! Yes, it should work. Edit: I thought you replaced the condition *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In C there are generally two ways to handle a single-linked list: As a stack or as a queue.

When handling the list as a stack, you add new items at the head. When handling it as a queue, you add new items at the tail.

---

The simplest is the stack-method:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

...

struct node *head = NULL;

/* Add one node */
struct node *n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n1->data = 1;
n1->next = head;   /* This and the next line is what adds the node */
head = n1;

/* Add another node */
struct node *n2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n2->data = 2;
n2->next = head;   /* This and the next line is what adds the node */
head = n2;
```

After the above code, the list contains two nodes:

```
2 --> 1 --> NULL
```

---

For the queue method you need to keep track of the tail as well as the head:

```
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *tail = NULL;

/* Add one node */
struct node *n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n1->data = 1;
n1->next = NULL;

if (tail != NULL)
    tail->next = n1;
else
{
    /* List is empty */
    head = tail = n1;
}

/* Add another node */
struct node *n2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
n2->data = 2;
n2->next = NULL;

if (tail != NULL)
    tail->next = n2;
else
{
    /* List is empty */
    head = tail = n2;
}
```

After this the list looks like

```
1 --> 2 --> NULL
```

---

I suggest you read this answer a couple of times, and think about how your handling of lists differ from the methods used here. I also suggest you use a debugger to step though your code, line by line, to see why your list handling will not work as expected.

Comment: I thought it was the other way. You implement stack and queue using singly linked list. Mostly because I can mix both approaches in SLL which makes it more general. It's not that relevant, but I don't think it's correct.